# JSDoc Typescript Declarations: How to automatically Register custom elements?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc, custom-element

Let's say I have a custom element definition, written in JavaScript with JSDoc annotations:

`my-element.js`:

```js
/** @element my-element */
export class MyElement extends HTMLElement { }
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

and a declaration file, generated using `declaration` and `allowJs`:

`my-element.d.ts`:

```js
/** @element my-element */
export class MyElement extends HTMLElement { }
```

I would like for typescript to automatically add the element to the `HTMLElementTagNameMap`.

My current workaround is to us a post-build script to concat this to the declaration file:

```sh
echo "declare global { interface HTMLElementTagNameMap { 'my-element': MyElement; } }" >> my-element.d.ts
```

Is there a better way to do this?